# How to improve the performance of the Jasmine-Blanket SpecRunner.html?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I have created test suites for my Backbone.js application using jasmine.js framework. I have 50 specs and my Backbone.js application has some remote service calls.

Whenever I am running my spec runner it takes around 10 to 15 mins to show the results. Same application is working very fast in some different machine. I am using Apache -Tomcat server , Eclipe IDE.

Is there anything wrong with application or something else?

How to improve the performance of the Jasmine-Blanket SpecRunner.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine spec runner will be execute at greater speed, If you are using **memcached / memcache**.

Jasmine spec runner speed depends on the application performance.  Try to use memcached or memcache to your application.

**I hope you did not run memcached to speed up your application.**

Javascript frameworks uses more .js files to develop any Mobile (web) applications. In this case, if you run memcached application, your system will be execute at good speed.

Your alternate system might be use (32 bit or 64 bit) memcached application. Better to check your alternate system(Mac).

Comment: yep, I did not run any of memcached / memcahed. After running Memached from my command prompt it works at great speed. Thanks.